# Define relations on the set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have had problems figuring out how to answer this question. The book we use does not go into detail on how to use mathematical notation for relations. Any help would be great! (have not tried anything cause I am not sure what to do)

Define the following relations on the set R: 
R1 = { (x, y): x ≤ y } 
R2 = { (x, y): x > y } 
R3 = { (x, y): x < y } 
R4 = { (x, y): x = y }

Use mathematical notation to describe the following relations:

R1 ∘ R2
R4 ∘ R2
R3 ∘ R4
R3 ∘ R2

Answer (score 1):

The relations you got consist of pairs of elements $(x,y) \in R^2$. (Not sure if your $R$ is the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$). They are binary relations.

You need the definition of how to form a new relation by composition (that is what the circle $\circ$ stands for) of two existing relations.
$$
R_1 \circ R_2 = \{ (x, z) \mid \ldots \}
$$

Example:

$$
R_1 \circ R_2 = \{ (x, z) \mid \exists y \in R: 
(x,y) \in R_2 \wedge (y, z) \in R_1 \}
$$
then
$$
(x, z) \in R_1 \circ R_2 \iff \\
\exists y\in R: x > y \wedge y \le z \iff \\
\exists y\in R: y < x \wedge y \le z 
$$ 
e.g. choose $y = \min(x - 1, z)$. This works for all $x, z \in R$, thus
$R_1 \circ R_2 = R^2$.

Example:
$$
(x, z) \in R_4 \circ R_2 \iff \\
\exists y\in R: x > y \wedge y = z \iff \\
x > z
$$
This means $R_4 \circ R_2 = R_2$.

Comment: I guess I am not 100% sure how I would turn that into an answer. I am asked to describe 4 different relations from that list, and I have no idea how to turn that into an answer for my assignment

Comment: @Summer Do you have any definition for what $R \circ S$ is supposed to mean?

Comment: @Summer It will be a new relation. So you can describe it like your $R_i$ are described, as subsets of $R^2$. The ambiguity is that $R\circ S$ is in general different from $S\circ R$ so you should stick to the definition the author used.

Comment: What is the def'n of RoS in the textbook?